# Recursive tree creation

Tags: c#, recursion

I have a `Node` class in C# with the following properties:

```
public class Node
{
   public int Id {get;set;}
   public int? ParentId {get;set;}
   public string Label {get;set;}
}
```

I have a `TreeView` control which provides the following method to create
a new node:

```
MyTreeView.CreateNode(key, label);
parent.Nodes.CreateNode(key, label);
```

If I want to add a new child node I need to use the second method otherwise the first one. Both returns an object of type `TreeNode`.

How would you create in C# a recursive function to populate the treeview considering that the root nodes have `ParentId = null`?

This is what I have done so far:

```
// create a list of root nodes
var roots = myList.Where(x => x.ParentId == null);
// send the roots to a recursive func
foreach(var root in roots)
{
   AddNode(null,root,myList);
}
```

this is my recursive function:

```
private void AddNode(Node parent, Node current, IList<Node> items)
{
   TreeNode treenode = null;
   if(parent == null)
   {
      treenode = mytree.CreateNode(current.Id.ToString(), current.Label);
   }else{
      var parentnode = mytree.GetNode(parent.Id.ToString());
      treenode = parentnode.Nodes.CreateNode(current.Id.ToString(), current.Label);
   }
   // call the recursion for the children
   var children = items.Where(x => x.ParentId == current.Id);
   foreach(var child in children)
   {
      AddNode(current, child, items);
   }
}
```

Comment: You need to add the C# tag. If this is homework, you should add the homework tag as well. Also, you should show us a code sample of what you have tried.

Comment: Ok, I will modify the post, thanks.

Comment: what is wrong with this function? besides the fact that you dont need the variable treenode

Comment: It is wrong because I have to accomplish everything into one call, what I am doing here is two calls. I though about adding an extension with LinQ but I am not so good with it.

Comment: You've forgotten to mention something which I feel is very important.  You're generating your tree based off of some sort of `IList`  What is in your list?  One can make an inference, but Can't know for sure

Comment: What do you mean by 2 calls? By definition of a recursive function, you need at least 2 calls: One for the first iteration and One for the recursion. And your function seems correct, even if it is far from being optimum.

Answer (score 2):

If your tree view control is derived from System.Windows.Forms.TreeView you can replace

```
MyTreeView.CreateNode(key, label);
parent.Nodes.CreateNode(key, label);
```

with

```
MyTreeView.Nodes.Add(key, label);
parent.Nodes.Add(key, label);
```

So the call always goes to a Nodes collection which is of type TreeNodeCollection. Instead of your Node object you can now use the Nodes collection as parameter.

```
var roots = myList.Where(x => x.ParentId == null);
foreach (var root in roots)
{
    AddNode(mytree.Nodes, root, myList);
}

private void AddNode(TreeNodeCollection nodes, Node current, IList<Node> items)
{
    TreeNode treenode = nodes.Add(current.Id.ToString(), current.Label);

    var children = items.Where(x => x.ParentId == current.Id);
    foreach (var child in children)
    {
        AddNode(treenode.Nodes, child, items);
    }
}
```

This has two benefits:

1. You don't need to lookup the parent each time.
2. You only have one call (TreeNodeCollection.Add).

However, if you can not access the TreeView.Nodes collection in the AddNode call for each root you will have to check for that at the top of the AddNode method.

```
var roots = myList.Where(x => x.ParentId == null);
foreach (var root in roots)
{
    AddNode(null, root, myList);
}

private void AddNode(TreeNodeCollection nodes, Node current, IList<Node> items)
{
    if (nodes == null)
    {
        nodes = myTree.Nodes;
    }

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
var lookup = myList.ToLookup(n => n.ParentId.ToString());

Action<IEnumerable<TreeNode>> addChildren = null;
addChildren = tns =>
{
    var query =
        from tn in tns
        from cn in lookup[tn.Name]
        select tn.Nodes.CreateNode(cn.Id.ToString(), cn.Label);
    var nodes = query.ToArray();
    if (nodes.Length > 0)
    {
        addChildren(nodes);
    }
};

addChildren(
    lookup[null]
        .Select(n =>
            MyTreeView.CreateNode(n.Id.ToString(), n.Label)));
```

I couldn't fully test it, so you might need to change some of the code to make it work, but it should be fairly close.

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably do something like this...

```
public class Node
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? ParentId { get; set; }
    public string Label { get; set; }

    public Node(int? parentId, int id, string label)
    {
        ParentId = parentId;
        Id = id;
        Label = label;
    }
}

public class TreeNode : List<TreeNode>
{
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public string Label { get; set; }


    public IEnumerable<TreeNode> Descendants
    {
        get
        {
            yield return this;

            foreach (var child in this)
            {
                foreach (var descendant in child.Descendants)
                {
                    yield return descendant;
                }

            }
        }
    }

    public TreeNode(string key, string label)
    {
        Key = key;
        Label = label;
    }

    public void CreateNode(int id, string label)
    {
        Add(new TreeNode(id.ToString(), label));
    }
}

public class Tree
{
    private TreeNode _root = new TreeNode(null, null);

    public Tree(IEnumerable<Node> nodes)
    {
        nodes.ToList().ForEach(node => CreateNode(node.ParentId, node.Id, node.Label));
    }

    public void CreateNode(int? parentId, int id, string label)
    {
        if (parentId == null)
        {
            _root.CreateNode(id, label);
        }
        else
        {
            _root.Descendants.First(x => x.Key == parentId.ToString()).CreateNode(id, label);
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<TreeNode> Descendants => _root.Descendants;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this code:

```
Node{
     Id, Label, List<Tree> Children
}

Tree GetTree(id){
     var node=new Node();
     
     node.Id=id;
     node.Children=new List<Node>();
     
     List<Node> children = db.Nodes.Where(x => x.ParentId==id);
     
     foreach(child in children){
           var childTree=GetTree(child.Id);
           node.Children.Add(childTree);
     }
     
     return node;
}
```